Pushing files to a local remote folder
I am new to git.
And would like following setup:
I have one folder Staging_folder where I put my programs once they are done. That folder is a git repository. That was really straightforward to implement.
Now I want another local folder (production_folder) to which I push the programs in the staging_folder with the push command.
The underlying idea is that the Staging_folder can contain changes which aren't captured by git because I forgot to run it.
To avoid that any code can be run that wasn't logged by git I want this extra folder and will exclusively run code from there.
I read this question:
Push Git Project to Local Directory
and made this --bare git repository. I can push to that and the master is there but the files are not in the folder on my filesystem.
Then I read this:
Local machine pushes branch but no files to Remote repo
and apparently the files aren't expected to be there but its also bad form to not have that remote repo be --bare?
What is the correct way to implement the process as I've laid out?

A bare repo is exactly a repo that has no "files in the filesystem". So if you do want the production folder to have "files in the filesystem", make it a non-bare repo. You are the only user of these repos, and you do not intend to do any actual work in the production folder, so that is an okay thing to do.
However, I would also suggest to you that this is a misuse of Git. The way to make sure that your work is or is not correctly checked into the Git repo in the staging folder is to use Git correctly in the staging folder itself. The production folder sounds superflous. If only certain files are to constitute the project for purposes of running the project, that sounds like a branch, not a whole nother copy of the repo.

You might find it helpful to read my https://www.biteinteractive.com/picturing-git-conceptions-and-misconceptions/

Thanks that was indeed helpful.
The point of doing the stuff above is to ensure that things are tracked in git before they get run. (other people may run them from the local folders)
As in there is no way git doesn't know about the files when they get run.
making it a non-bare repo throws me errors (which I could ignore) but I'm trying to use git properly.
Is git not the right tool to do this?
Basically I wouldn't even need the remote stuff to be tracked in git, I just need the files to only appear there if git knows of them.

Well, why not have three repos? You push to the bare repo (no errors there) and then pull to a clone of the bare repo and run from that (because normal clones do have a working tree, aka "files in the filesystem").
